# Nullable datetime conversion error

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, nullable

I am reading field values which may have an unformatted date in them or whitespace, i need to convert the string in the filled fields to datetime and write it back. I'm trying the following but get the error "Nullable object must have a value":

```
DateTime? localVersion = null;
DateTime? serverVersion = null;

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.cellValueLocal))
{
    localVersion = DateTime.ParseExact(item.cellValueLocal, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.cellValueServer))
{
    serverVersion = DateTime.ParseExact(item.cellValueServer, "ddMMyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

localVersion.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
serverVersion.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Can anyone offer any guidance on what the issue might be here please?

Comment: Which line actually errors though?

Comment: Try to set them to a default value such as `DateTime? localVersion = new DateTime(2015, 1, 18);`'

Comment: What do you expect to happen if (say) `item.cellValueLocal` *is* null or whitespace?

Comment: It just needs to write back whitespace to that cell. Any cells with the unformatted datetime just need to parsed to date time for processing then written back as a string in the new format.

Comment: What are the final two lines supposed to be doing? There's no point calling ToString without assigning the returned string to anything.

Comment: Think about what @JonSkeet is saying. If the value is a string or whitespace, `localVersion` and `serverVersion` won't have a value you can call `toString()` on.

Comment: Additionally, what do you expect the last lines to achieve when they *do* work? You're calling `ToString()`, but not doing anything with the return value.

Comment: you should always user DateTime.TryParseExact if there is any possibility that the format wont match, also you need to add null checks to anywhere you access nullable<T>.Value

Answer (score 3):

If your cellValue is null (or whitespace), your DateTime instances will not be initialized and still be set to `null`. You cannot access `.Value` on a nullable instance without a value.
You have to check with `.HasValue` first:

```
if (localVersion.HasValue) {
  localVersion.Value.ToString(...);
}
```

Comment: This won't actually do anything since you're not assigning the result of the `ToString` call to a variable.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: yes. Execute additional code as needed …

Answer (score 1):

The lines:

```
localVersion.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
serverVersion.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Are errors. If `item.cellValueLocal` or `item.cellValueServer` is null or empty then `localVersion.Value` and `serverVersion.Value` will never be assigned a non-null value, and therefore `Value` will throw an exception when you access it.

You need to replace the operations with:

```
if (localVersion.HasValue)
    localVersion.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Alternatively you could use the null coalescing operator:

```
DateTime version = localVersion ?? DateTime.Now;
```

Replacing `DateTime.Now` with an appropriate default value. In C# 6 you can use the `?.` syntax to simplify it further to:

```
string version = localVersion?.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ?? String.Empty;
```

Which does the null check inline.

Comment: Actually `Value` isn't `null` in that case it's just that the `Nullable<T>` type guards access to `Value` based on `HasValue` being false.

Comment: @juharr - Fair enough, I changed the wording.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling the latest version of c# (6.0) compiler then you could shorten this further to be

```
localVersion?.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: This will do nothing as you're not assigning the result of the `ToString` call to a variable.